# How to dynamically load a module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I'm trying to dynamically load modules. I've seen many questions on this topic - but none helped.

I've got this directory structure:

```
root
|-- tests
|---- test_modules
|------ modules (files=test.py, __init__.py)
|-------- module1 (files=module.py, __init__.py)
|-------- module2 (files=module.py, __init__.py)
```

I would like to import module1 and module2 into test.py under the modules dir.

I'm trying to use variations on this:

```
module1 = __import__('modules.module1.module', fromlist=['module'])
or
module1 = __import__('modules.module1.module')
```

I always get the same error 'No module named *'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Worked for me, have you tried with a minimal example of empty files?

Comment: that's really strange. I've now delete all content from the files. still same error.

Comment: Can you post the import statement from test.py?

Comment: Found the problem. Thanks :) Was the '__init__.py' file in modules folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import importlib
module1 = importlib.import_module('module1.module')
module2 = importlib.import_module('module2.module')
```

That said, `__import__` should work too. You just need to take out the "modules" at the beginning, like so (I've set up a similar directory structure to you):

```
In [3]: __import__('module1.module')
Out[3]: <module 'module1' from 'module1/__init__.py'>
```

Comment: There's a problem in one of your modules, then -- that structure works fine for me. What do `module1/module.py` and `module2/module.py` look like? Are you doing a `*` import in any of them?

Comment: hmm. the module files include just one method 'get_name()' that's all. might be something else needed?

Comment: Are you doing `import *` for some reason anywhere in the code? How about in either of the `__init__.py` files?

Comment: If you open a Python shell in tests/test_modules/modules and do "import module1.module", does that work?

Comment: seems like the 'test.py' file doesn't see the 'modules' folder

Comment: OK. Found what the problem was - the '__init__.py' wasn't really in the modules folder. After adding it there - all works great. Many thanks for the help :)